# Optimal relational design for groups and subgroup relationships

Tags: postgresql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I have a bit of an intro-level relational database design question. I'm working on a project where I'm capturing information from scientific journal articles and storing that in a Postgres database. One of my primary goals is to define a schema that is flexible enough to cover *most* cases I might encounter in a broad set of papers. In reality, articles tend to report a semi-standard set of details, but there's definitely variance once you get into the details. These things are written for humans, not machines.

For the most part, defining the schema has been pretty straightforward, but one thing I'm stuck on is how to sensibly structure a set of tables to capture details about a study's subject groups and subsets of subjects.

Take for example a simple randomized control trial - you typically have a set of people identified as screened for eligibility, a set determined to be eligible, a set randomized into the control group, and a set randomized into the treatment group. Within each of those groups you can have subgroups defined in all sorts of specific ways, but generally by some sort of interval (e.g. Age 26-32) or a category (e.g. pregnant/not pregnant).

Currently, I've set this up so that a `Study` record can have many `Subject` records, and `Subject` records can have many `Interval_Subgroup` records and many `Categorical_Subgroup` records.

```
Subject
-----------------------------------------
id | groupType  | measure | value | study
-----------------------------------------
13 |  treatment |  count  |  578  |  17
14 |   control  |  count  |  552  |  17

Interval_Subgroup
---------------------------------------------------------------
id | factor | factorMin | factorMax | measure | value | subject
---------------------------------------------------------------
41 |  age   |     18    |     24    |  count  |  125  |   13   
42 |  age   |     25    |     32    |  count  |  204  |   13   

Categorical_Subgroup
-----------------------------------------------------
id | factor | factorValue | measure | value | subject
-----------------------------------------------------
74 |  sex   |     male    |  count  |  251  |   13   
75 |  sex   |    female   |  count  |  327  |   13
```

This seems workable, but feels clunky because I have two tables for capturing the same type of information. Also it's limiting because it wouldn't allow me to capture any combination of subgroup sets like males of age 18-24. Some studies report that kind of detail, some don't, but I want to be able to capture any depth of subgroup info the paper offers.

What is a more flexible way to structure these tables than what I've described above? I'm trying to sketch out how I think this should work, and right now, I have subject groups having many subgroups and subgroups having many subgroup definitions. There would just be one table capturing measurements about subgroups, and another table for defining what each subgroup is. I'm not sure if that is in the right direction. Maybe there is a far more simple solution that you might know of.

Thanks for taking the time to help out - it's much appreciated!

---

Edit:
Fixed id to be unique in the example tables.

Comment: Why couldn't you get males 18-24 with this setup-- I'd sure think you could-- just add more records.. other options would work just be one way or another of combining criteria into one record set (think putting ALL those columns into one table).

Comment: As they are, I think the two subgroup tables only work for single-component factors. Combining the criteria fields into a single table would perhaps tidy things up, but it wouldn't allow me to assign multiple defining criteria to a single subgroup. If I wanted to store the count of individuals who are TB+, female, and aged 18-24, this setup seems to not allow that.

Comment: And thus: you are basically reinventing the EAV model here (which is not so bad in this case) You **do** need an extra layer of constraints, such that a person (or group) cannot be part of two age groups, etc.

Comment: Thanks @wildplasser, I'm going to need to read up on the EAV model.

Comment: Do realise: this kind of stuff (multiple sources/multiple semantics) is hard/impossible to model. Just don't overdo it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it sounds like a `factor` is a *thing*, and that each `subgroup` has one or more `factor`s. To me this implies that `factor` needs its own table. Factors can in turn be of type `interval` or `categorical`, which means [single table inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Table_Inheritance) might be in order.

Example tables might look something like this:

```
subgroups
------------------------------
id | measure | value | subject
------------------------------
41 |  count  |  125  |   13   
42 |  count  |  204  |   13   

factors
id | type        | factor | category | interval_min | interval_max | subgroup
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
68 | interval    | age    | NULL     | 18           | 24           | 13
69 | categorical | sex    | male     | NULL         | NULL         | 13
```

In this example subgroup 41 has two factors, age 18-24 and gender male.

It could also be that STI is overkill here, in which case you'd split `factor` into two tables, `categorical_factors` and `interval_factors`, and a subgroup could have zero or many of each.

As far as I'm aware, the complexity of using STI mostly depends on what ORM you're using. Rails / ActiveRecord has good support, other frameworks vary.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Dan - that's certainly helpful. I think STI might actually simplify things on the ORM side.